# Xcode organizer shows crash reports of unsupported device

Tags: ios, xcode

We launched our iOS camera app only for iPhones and we do not support any other apple devices. We have **telephony** in  **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** which iPads don't support.(Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html))

But in Xcode -> Organizer -> Crashes we are receiving crash logs from iPads.

In iTunes connect analytics, the number of app units vs device shows 100% iPhone. So where are we getting these iPad crash logs from? How can someone download the app on iPad if we are not supporting it?

PS: The logs have correct info i.e., if we test our app on iPad the crash log we get matches the crash log in Xcode Organizer.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone-only apps can be downloaded from the App Store to an iPad regardless of whether or not you support using it the iPad.  This is different than iPad-only apps because those can't be installed on an iPhone (non-jailbreak).

A user simply has to select to download the iPhone version to their iPad and they can download it.  The app will display on their iPad in 'compatibility mode', that's as a smaller (screen size) app or magnified to fit the iPad screen.

Just because people are using iPads doesn't mean you have to provide them support.  You can always refuse support to someone if they've used your app on an 'unsupported device'.  Just be sure to clearly call out that it's not designed to run on iPads in your app description.

In iTunesConnect, you're only seeing users who have approved to share analytics and logs with both Apple and the app's developer.  That audience might only contain people with iPhones that agreed to share the logs so you're only going to see iPhones in the logs (this is why I use a 3rd-party analytics tool in addition to the regular ones from Apple).

Comment: Thanks. We have a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key set to include telephony, which should exclude iPads. Why are we still seeing them in crash reports? The app in question is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/noctacam/id1240793690?mt=8

Comment: What key are you using to restrict it to iPhone only?  My reading of the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) doesn't show how this can be done to achieve your desired affect.  In fact, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035404/can-i-use-uirequireddevicecapabilities-to-restrict-an-app-to-ipads-and-the-iphon) on SO seems to indicate it can't be used that way.

Comment: As I wrote, the key is telephony, which only iPhones support.

Comment: What about iPads that have cellular capabilities?  Does this key restrict usage from those?

Comment: Yes, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html says that no iPad has telephony.